# From raspi to laptop python3 vb.net/c#

Tags: python, c

Hello im enquiring about using data from a raspb-pi via python to then access it in c# in visual studio for an impending app I will make, what is the best way to go about this.

To extend atm I am using my raspberry pi as a ad-hoc network with a static ip address and would like to connect the two with a program that will allow me to do it wireless.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, but what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: Basically the best way to communicate between a raspi pi and your laptop but it has been answered below thanks doe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sockets would be the standard network solution.

Use TCP/IP if you want guaranteed in-order delivery or UDP if that isn't a concern.

I've used TCP/IP to deliver over 100,000 12 byte messages per second from Pis.

Comment: oh thanks for advice, just wondering whether you have used upd in visual studios when your writing the function to receive the sockets sent from the raspberry pi, how you manage to include the ip address of your raspberry pi?

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio for decades so can't help with that.  Generally you'd use the host name rather than the IP address.  i.e. get the address with the C function getaddrinfo and pass that to the socket call.  getaddrinfo is POSIX so should be available under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate between the Raspberry Pi and a C# or VB.NET using Serial. You will need a a breakout board for the [FTDI FT232RL USB to serial IC](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716). There are a bunch of tutorials online.

You can also use [NRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Antenna Wireless Transceiver Module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FDPTUC6) for wireless communications. Once again, lots of tutorials online.

Comment: sorry to extend to give you more info atm I am using my raspberry pi as a ad-hoc network with a static ip address and would like to connect the two with a program that will allow me to do it wireless.

Comment: I added some wireless solutions

Comment: @user2520014 - if you find that I have answered your question, please mark as answered - thanks